# Connection refuse postgresql when use docker with Laravel

Tags: laravel, postgresql, docker

I've been trying for a few hours to make a connection between laravel and the docker database and try a migrated php artisan
Everything starts correctly but I run into the problem that I can't connect the laravel to the database
Do you have any idea why this is happening?
This is my env

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=postgres
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=smart
DB_USERNAME=admin
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

My docker file

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libpng-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        libonig-dev \
        zip \
        curl \
        unzip \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && docker-php-source delete \
    && apt-get install -y postgresql-client
```

And my docker yml

```
services: 
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
    image: 'server'
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
database:
    image: postgres
    container_name: database
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secret
        POSTGRES_DB: smart
        POSTGRES_USER: admin
    volumes:
        - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
        - '5432:5432'
```

The problem is, I can't figure out exactly why this is happening. The laravel server works perfectly, I can access it but when I connect the database everything breaks down

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = public and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

EDIT::
Apparently I can't connect. to the database because it doesn't start as I would have liked, I can't even access it from the url how do I access the laravel server, opinions?

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have installed the postgres driver in your docker environment.
Add this to your script.

`&& docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql`